# Return html view from controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Since I upgraded my application to .Net Core 3.0, I can't return a html view from a controller.

If I call View("Views/test.html"), it says it doesn't find the file. In 2.2, it worked well...

Any idea on the breaking change that made my code broken ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to request static HTML files, add them under `wwwroot` or create a  directory inside it , for example , html folder , and serve that as well via the static files middleware . Then you can return the html to view with `text/html` content-type :

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return File("/html/test.html", "text/html");
}
```

Comment: What namespace of File()?  System.IO doesn't seem to do it for me in .Net Core 6

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

Finally, I modifier StaticFiles Middleware configuration to serve also html files that are not in the wwwroot folder using this code :

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
       Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "MyFiles/MyAngularJSApplication")),
    RequestPath = "/app",
});
```

see : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.0